# Can the word "alors" mean "et puis {and then}" ?

Tags: sens

> Il me fallait trouver un autre solution. C'était évident. **Alors**, il m'a dit connaître quelqu'un en mesure de m'y aider.

Given the context, I think that the "alors" here means "**and then {et puis}**", indicating that A happens first and then B happens afterwards.

None of the other possible meanings of "alors" (namely "**so {donc}**", "**back then {à l'époque}**", and "**in that case {dans ce cas}**") does not seem to fit perfectly in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can indeed have a temporal meaning, to convey *« at that moment »*.
In a context like story-telling, more specifically, it really means « at that moment *of the story/action* »

Anecdotically to your question, the TLFi article ([here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alors)) happens to quote this meaning as the very first of its long list.

Comment: So I suppose that the "ensuite" meaning is off the mark? Merci.